# How do you reliably create a GraphQL/Twig theme as a subtheme?

Tags: theming

Our theme is built with GraphQL Twig and it's working great. We need to build a subtheme for a different website based on this theme. We're not really having a problem overriding simple Atoms templates, but once you start getting more complex, the site won't recognize the existence of the new templates. Instead, the site keeps using the old templates. I can't go in and change the location of the referenced child template in the higher-level parent templates because they are all part of the base theme. Were we to have to go through and change these locations in all the code, we'd be duplicating so many templates in the subtheme that we might as well just copy/paste the entire base theme and just have divergent code (two base themes). This really isn't something we want to do. We want to be able to maintain the base theme with slight changes to the subtheme.

For example, we have a paragraph which needs three additional fields added to it in the subtheme. In a site without GraphQL, we would simply add the fields to the paragraph.twig. In this theme, however, the field variables come from the container and are passed to the paragraph. Adding the field-container doesn't work either as it is referenced in the landing page, page, and news content types, all of which reference these templates. If we don't include all of these templates in the subtheme, the subtheme cannot find them because they are not physically in the subtheme folders. Some of those folders don't even exist in the subtheme because we aren't overriding the templates inside them.

```
themes
  - contrib
     - our_base_graphql_theme
        - storybook
           - 01-base
           - 02-atoms
           - 03-molecules
              - our-paragraph
                 - our-paragraph.twig
           - 04-organisms
              - our-field-container
                 - our-field-container.twig
           - 05-templates
           - 06-pages
              - our-landing-page
                 - our-landing-page.twig 
              - our-page
                 - our-page.twig 
              - our-news
                 - our-news.twig 
  - custom
     - our_subtheme
        - storybook
           - 03-molecules
              - overrides
                 - our-paragraph
                    - our-paragraph.twig
```

Snippet from field container template our-field-container.twig:

```
{% if type == 'our-paragraph' %}
  {% include '@storybook/03-molecules/our-paragraph/our-paragraph.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

Snippet from content type templates such as our-landing-page.twig:

```
  {# The field container #}
  <div class="lower-content">
      {% include '@storybook/04-organisms/our-field-container/our-field-container.twig' %}
  </div>
```

I don't think we should have to copy all of the theme templates in order to override just one field. I'm certain I am missing something, but the documentation online is slim.

How can I fix this problem?